# thd (triggerhappy global hotkey daemon) - necessary?

Tags: raspbian

Has `thd` any vital roles on a Raspbian system?

I've never used this daemon before, and I don't know what it exactly does. I'm preparing a RPi for a remote hosting location, so it will be a headless, SSH only machine.

Is it safe to remove or does it serve any special purpose?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/wertarbyte/triggerhappy/blob/master/README):

> Triggerhappy is a hotkey daemon developed with small and embedded systems in
> mind, e.g. linux based routers. It attaches to the input device files and
> interprets the event data received and executes scripts configured in its
> configuration.

Keyboard volume control is one of the areas where it proves useful, according to [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=53916&p=411882).

Based on that, it probably won't be of much use in the remote headless scenario for most people, but given its versatility it can be used in many other interesting situations. One such example is shutting down a headless Raspberry Pi with a mouse button. See [this post on hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/shut-down-your-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way-9c7be0b4fff8) for details on how to do that.
If you often find yourself ssh'ing onto your Pi (or connecting a keyboard and display) to launch some simple command (like shutdown), `thd` might be for you.

Comment: Its incredibly useful on a headless machine, you can plug a controller in and press a button to control it!

Comment: Just to add... if you do want to remove it, run `sudo apt-get remove triggerhappy`